# How to catch multiple exceptions in Clojure?

Tags: java, exception, clojure

My Clojure code has some java-interop with a method that throws multiple exceptions. I wish to deal with each individual of them. According to Clojure documentation:

```
(try expr* catch-clause* finally-clause?)
catch-clause -> (catch classname name expr*)
```

it has no mention of catching multiple exceptions. Is it possible to do so in Clojure?

Thank you!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's the same as in Java, you can declare several `catch` expressions one after the other, and they'll get matched in the same order they were declared - first `Exception1`, if it doesn't match then `Exception2` and so on, and the `finally` part will always be executed.

```
(try <some code>
    (catch Exception1 e1 (prn "in catch1"))
    (catch Exception2 e2 (prn "in catch2"))
    (finally (prn "in finally")))
```

In fact, this is specified in the documentation, `(try expr* catch-clause* finally-clause?)` means that you can have "zero or more expressions", "zero or more catch clauses" and "zero or one finally clauses" as part of a `try` expression.

Comment: The good ol' [Kleene star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star), it never disappoints me :)