# Catch multiple exceptions in Clojure and handle them the same

Tags: clojure, exception

This is a bit similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875025/how-to-catch-multiple-exceptions-in-clojure), but I want to catch multiple exceptions and handle them all the same. In Ruby, I can write

```
begin
  rand(2) == 0 ? ([] + '') : (foo)
rescue TypeError, NameError => e
  puts "oops: #{e.message}"
end
```

Can I do the same in Clojure? For now I `let` a function and just call it in each `catch` body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple built-in solution for that yet, however, there is an [open ticket](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-2124).

You can write a dispatch on type in the catch block by hand.

```
(try
  (do-dangerous-operation-here)
  (catch Exception e
    (condp (fn [cs t] (some #(instance? % t) cs)) e

      [IllegalStateException IllegalArgumentException]
      (println "Either illegal state or illegal argument!")

      [java.sql.SQLException]
      (println "Sql error!")

      ;; whe pass through the exception when not handled
      (throw e))))
```

Answer (score 8):

```
(ns mastering.stackoverflow
    (:use
        [slingshot.slingshot :only [try+]]))


(try+
    ; ...
    (catch (comp #{TypeError NameError} class) _ "caught"))
```

[The slingshot library](https://github.com/scgilardi/slingshot) is available on github.

Answer (score 2):

You could also delegate to a local function, although it gets a little verbose:

```
(let [handle #(println %)]
  (try
    (throwing-op)

    (catch TypeError e (handle e))
    (catch NameError e (handle e))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this macro:

```
(defmacro try*
  "Macro to catch multiple exceptions with one catch body.
   Usage:
   (try*
     (println :a)
     (println :b)
     (catch* [A B] e (println (class e)))
     (catch C e (println :C))
     (finally (println :finally-clause)))
   Will be expanded to:
   (try
     (println :a)
     (println :b)
     (catch A e (println (class e)))
     (catch B e (println (class e)))
     (catch C e (println :C))
     (finally (println :finally-clause)))
  "
  [& body]
  (letfn [(catch*? [form]
            (and (seq form)
                 (= (first form) 'catch*)))
          (expand [[_catch* classes & catch-tail]]
            (map #(list* 'catch % catch-tail) classes))
          (transform [form]
            (if (catch*? form)
              (expand form)
              [form]))]
    (cons 'try (mapcat transform body))))
```

credits https://gist.github.com/Gonzih/5814945